# How can I check output of webpack merge

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to run the google closure compiler over my webpack assets, but am getting warnings about issues in the webpack styles loaders. But I thought that the style loaders were not going to be in any of the js assets as I was using the MiniCssExtractPlugin to get a separate css file.

Two questions:

- how can I get access to the output of by webpack.config.js in production mode? (Can i do something on the command line to see what the merge result is?)
- how can I get the merge to work as I had expected, i.e. not using style-loader for production?

**Code:**

```
const merge = require("webpack-merge");

var common = {
    ....
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
                // see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#url
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader?url=false", "sass-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader?url=false"]
            },
...

if (MODE === "production") {
    module.exports = merge(common, {
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
              new ClosurePlugin({mode: 'STANDARD'}, {})
            ]
          },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
                    loaders: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        "css-loader?url=false"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
                    loaders: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        "css-loader?url=false",
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (I'm using webpack 4).
My configuration is splitted on 3 files : common, dev and prod ; as [webpack guide explain](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/);

To log merged config, you can do something like :

```js
var merged_config = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [ 
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader', 
                    'less-loader'
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ]
});

module.exports = merged_config;

console.log(JSON.stringify(merged_config));
```

And as you can see in the code above, I override rules to generate a css bundle in production mode. Inside my common config, I have this :

```js
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
            },
            { 
                test: /\.html$/, 
                loader: 'raw-loader' 
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [ 
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader', 
                    'less-loader'
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
```

And it works as I expected !

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked great for me. Thank you!

Comment: For me the statement to print a combined webpack config via `console.log(JSON.stringify(merged_config));`  lost fidelity with the original config.  It didn't render any of the test RegEx content, which is what I needed most to see.  The plugin [webpack-config-dump-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-config-dump-plugin) had a much better representation,  Plus it automatically dumps to a file that your IDE can reformat for easy viewing.  Got good results with options obj:`{name: 'webpack.config.dump.js', keepCircularReferences: true,includeFalseValues: true}`

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(merged_config, null, 2));` for pretty printing